# Passing arguments to mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am trying to write a program in Python that accepts the user inputs and queries from the MySQL database.
My database has the following tables:-

1. Departments(dept_no (primary key), dept_name)
2. Employees(emp_no(primary key), f_name, l_name, dob, hire_date)
3. Salaries(emp_no(primary key), salary, from_date(primary key), to_date)

When I give the following input:- Display the employees with salary greater than 20000.

Then the program should perform the following action:-

```python
from sqlite3 import Error
from MySQLdb import connect


def mysql_code():
    try:
        with connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="root", database="employees") as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("SELECT e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name, s.salary from employees e inner join "
                               "salaries s on e.emp_no = s.emp_no where s.salary > '20000'")
                records = cursor.fetchall()
                print(records)
            print("Total results found = ", cursor.rowcount)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

and display the results.

Is it possible to do so or do I have to write code for each possible query?

I previously used:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {} like %s".format(table, column), (text,))
```

When I defined the query and gave the user options to choose from where I wrote a query for each of the possible user inputs like

1. to display all records,
2. search records with the first name and so on. When the user chose an option the result was displayed.

Now I want the user to give inputs such as
`Display employees with salaries greater than 20000 working in dept_no d002.` or similar queries.

The program should accept queries in the form of a string from the user.

The code should join the tables and display the result by joining the `emp_no`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `salary`, `dept_no` from the tables `employees`, `salaries` and `departments` respectively.

Comment: your query is a string, so if you pass a sting, it will be sent to the server, but to generate valid code, for user input you have to write a complier for the user input and that will be very timecinsuming. but you can let the user choose the columns and the tables and construct a sql code, nothing else makes  eloquent or txpeorm too

Comment: If you want your users to input the question with natural language, parsing it will require a way to process natural language, and this is a completely different problem. I don't know how you expect to translate from natural language to code, but the answers you'll get from this question will assume there's a limited number of options that you're going to select. Check this to begin to understand what NLP is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in your code the like after the on comparison is wrong

```
from sqlite3 import Error
from MySQLdb import connect


def mysql_code():
    try:
        with connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="root", database="employees") as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("SELECT e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name, s.salary from employees e inner join "
                               "salaries s on e.emp_no = s.emp_no  where s.salary > '20000'")
                records = cursor.fetchall()
                print(records)
            print("Total results found = ", cursor.rowcount)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 'like' from when I modified the code from another query.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to perform customizable MySQL queries in Python, creating a constant function and passing it the query.

For this I would use [`f`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) strings. With this you would create a string query

```python
cursor.execute(f"SELECT {values_to_select} \
  from {table_name} \
  where {filters} \
  {more_stuff/extra_queries}")
```

This way you can pass the values to the function and it will perform the query with the values specified.

**Note:** As a test this is fine, but if this code is going to be used in production, giving the end user access to queries can be a huge security risk, checkout [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to see how these kinds of attacks happen. I would recommend to sanitize the given strings first so they can't create custom SQL queries.

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {} like %s".format(table, column), (text,)) I used this to perform tasks when I defined the query and gave the user an options to choose from. So I wrote a query for the user inputs like 1. to display all records, 2. search records with first name and so on. When the user chose an option the result was displayed.

Comment: Now I want the user to give inputs such as:- Display employees with salaries greater than 20000 working in dept d002. or similar queries. The code should join the tables and display the result. By joining the emp_no, first_name, last_name, salary, dept_no from employee table, salary table, departments table respectively.